# Free up memory in C creating issue

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, structure

I have a structure

```
typedef struct
{
char * name;
Player players[10];
}Team;
```

The memory is getting leak beacuse I am using malloc in initializeTeam.

```
Team * initializeTeam(int players, char *name)
{
int i=0;
Team *teama=malloc(sizeof(*teama));
teama->name=name;
for(i=0 ; i < players ; i++)
{
  teama->players[i].defensive=((rand() % 7) + 1);
    teama->players[i].offensive=((rand() % 10) + 1);
}

return teama;
};
```

I want memory not to leak.
The way is I can use free(teama);, if I use it the value is getting lost, as I am returning teama I want value to stay.

How can I go about it?

Comment: Call `free` somewhere else? When you don't need the memory any more?

Comment: If I am freeing it outside it gives an error conflicting types for ‘free’

Comment: You use malloc to create team. Use free when you finished to use team, after the return

Comment: If you could tell how I can go about it.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, especially how you use this `initializeTeam` function and what you assign the result to.

Comment: Conflicting types for `free()` is a separate problem — it's as if you've created your own function `free()` that you call to release the memory (though there may be other ways to run into the problem too).  Your initialize function is OK; it should not call `free()`.  It also doesn't need a semicolon after the final `}`.

Comment: Oh, you *do* `#include <stdlib.h>`?